# Are parking lots allowed to ticket for a higher price than listed

Tags: contract-law, canada, parking, fines

I recently received a parking ticket when forgetting to pay at a parking lot. However, it seems they increased their ticket price without changing any of their signage.

The sign at the entrance clearly states a $70 ticket for failure to pay, but I was charged $80.

Are they allowed to do this? Didn't the signage infer an agreement on the terms of using the parking lot, and any applicable fees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically the signage **implied** an agreement, and allowed you to infer one.

But yes, I think that management could not legally insist on more than the posted price, whether for a lost ticket, or for a particular duration.  (Unless the sign included "prices subject to change without notice" or something of the sort.)

As a practical matter, challenge this is going to be a pain. The employees on the spot probably have no authority to vary the price merely because the amount programmed into the register differs from the posted sign. At least they will claim not to have such authority. And they won't release the car without being paid the $80 that they will insist is the proper price.  To challenge this, a person would probably have to pay under protest, and then sue for a refund, I would hope in a small claims court. Most people will not go to that trouble for $10, which perhaps the management counts on. Publicity might be more effective.

Comment: I'll add that I have indeed sued a company in small claims court for 45 dollars in a situation just like this. I did it just to prove a point. They also paid me the 45 plus the filing fee, court and service costs. They kept up with their signage after that too.

Comment: Yeah I very well might do that haha. Just the kind of **** disturber that I am.